# Can a function have a Big O Complexity of O(-n)?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I've come across this question in my study for an exam and am not sure how to arrive at the answer. It comes across as potentially O(1) (constant time complexity) but what gets me is that if a larger input was given, it would take a lesser amount of time than if a smaller input was given. I believe this because the number that x begins at is related to the length of the input and the while loop finishes at the same x value for all inputs. For example, an input of list with 5 items, which would put the starting x value at 5, will have to loop many more times than an input of a list with 5^10 items, because the starting x value is higher.

Question:

What is the big-oh complexity of the following function?

```py
def foo(xs: List[int]):
    n = len(xs)
    while n < 10**10:
        n += 1
    return n
```

Comment: This is not actually a question about Python, or a question about writing code, but purely about the academic theory. Please try [cs.se].

Answer (score 1):

No, a complexity of O(-n) makes no sense.  Look at the [formal definition of Big O notation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) and see what happens when you define `g(x) = -x`.

First of all, the formal definition says `g(x)` should be strictly positive for large enough values of `x`.  But if we ignore that and continue reading the defintion, we see that it is impossible to pick a real positive number M and x0 that satisfy this condition:

[image: absolute value of f(x) is less than or equal to M times g(x) for all x greather than or equal to x0]

The left hand side would be zero or positive, while the right hand side of that inequality would be negative, so the inequality can never be true.

Since we can't pick those numbers, we cannot say `f(x)` is `O(-x)`.  And we didn't make any assumptions about `f`.

The Python function you wrote is `O(1)` because for sufficiently large inputs the while loop doesn't run at all.  You can set `x0` to `10**10` and apply the formal definition of Big O Notation if you're not convinced.

Answer (score 0):

O() is about what happens when n gets really big. If there is any N such that, for n>N, f(n) takes longer than g(n), then f(n) is at least O(g(n)). It doesn't matter how large N is; it can be `10**10`, `10**(10**10)`, etc., but as long as it's a finite number, it doesn't matter what happens for n<N. So your function isn't O(-n), and no function can be, because eventually it would take an negative amount of time to finish.

Also, O() isn't about the slope of the function, it's about its ratio to other functions. O(-n) would mean that f(n)/(-n) approaches a constant, not that f'(n) approaches -1. If f(n)/(-n) is a (positive) constant, then that means that f(n) takes a negative amount of time.